# asp.net MVC 4 - output list of checkbox items, associate selections with user - allow display & editing later

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

ASP.NET C# MVC 4 Code First application - in Visual Studio 2012 Express, SQL Server 2012 Express.

I have a places object. I would like to output the name of all places in a list - with a check box next to each.

I would then like logged in users to select the places they like - and have that saved. Then later they can login and see a them all again, with the appropriate check boxes selected.

What is the best approach? I'm new to MVC and not sure of best practice here.

thanks

**Update**

The below CheckboxListFor helper worked great, though it wasn't obvious how to process the user selection (it just returns a list of IDs).

I created the below to take that list of IDs - convert it to a list of objects, and add it to the SelecteCities list in the view model. This will select all the checkboxes that the user selected before the page was posted:

```
public ActionResult Examples(PostedCities postedCities)
{
 // ViewModel
 CitiesViewModel cvm = new CitiesViewModel();

 // Create list of cities
 List<City> cities = new List<City>{
  new City { Id = 1, Name = "London"},
  new City { Id = 2, Name = "Saigon"},
  new City { Id = 3, Name = "New York"}
 };

 // Assign list of cities to ViewModel 
 cvm.AvailableCities = cities;

 // If posted cities present, user posted something (else probably first call)
 if (postedCities.CityIDs != null)
 {
    // temporary city object
    City cty = new City();

    // List of selected cities
    List<City> selCities = new List<City>();

    // Go through each postedCity ID
    foreach (string s in postedCities.CityIDs)
    {
       // Get ID of postedCity
       int IdSel = Convert.ToInt32(s);

       // Lookup city Id in cities
       cty = cities.Single(c => c.Id == IdSel);

       // Add selected city to cty object
       selCities.Add(cty);
    }

    // Fill cvm.SelectedCities with selCities
    cvm.SelectedCities = selCities;
 }

return View(cvm);
}
```

This works - is it a good approach or have I overcomplicated it? Or done something badly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save yourself the work and use the existing MvcCheckBoxList library.

Install it with nuget using the command:

```
PM> Install-Package MvcCheckBoxList
```

Here is their home page: [MvcCheckBoxList](https://github.com/mikhail-tsennykh/MvcCheckBoxList)
And here is the documentation: [MvcCheckBoxList/Documentation](https://github.com/mikhail-tsennykh/MvcCheckBoxList)

Other solutions will require some ugly coding.

**Update**

As *Klas Mellbourn* suggested (I'm sorry for taking it for granted) a view model with a list will be the best practice for such sceneria. The documentation link I provided contains such examples for you to understand more easily.

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful.

Only thing I'm slightly unclear on (the examples don't cover it) - would be how to take the user input, and display it (as their examples do in text) - or use it to select the appropriate check boxes after server round trip (or a later page load).

Comment: If you have the appropriate list in your view model and it's polpulated with the correct values, calling CheckBoxListFor and supplying a lambda that acceses this property will automaticly create what you want and check the checkboxes that are marked as true in your view model.

Comment: After the user selects, say, 2 cities, and clicks submit - the controller receives PostedCities - a string array, with the ID of selected cities in. Works fine.

How do I get from there to a rendered page with those ID's selected?

Comment: What I'm not clear on is, once the user has selected some cities and posted that back to the controller, how I take postedCities - a string[], and apply that to the ViewModel to SelectedCities - a List<City>. @NofBar

I'm sure I'm missing something / there's an easy solution.

Comment: I have added some code in my original post that works - is it good?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that MVC best practices would be to have a viewmodel mirroring the fields you wish to display. It would contain a List with items, each item containing a placename string and a bool for the checkbox.

In the controller method that displays the page you build the view model based on the places objects that you have populated from the database using Entity Framework.

The users presumably save the state using some command, a submit button perhaps. This calls a second controller method that reads the viewmodel and persists the content using Entity Framework.

Comment: Thanks for the assist.

I have pasted some code in my original question that handles a post back and selecting the checkboxes that the user selected before postback.

Does it look OK to you? thx...